# Who pays for the content stored in a sharedCloudDatabase

Tags: cloudkit

On https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1640408-sharedclouddatabase it states:

> Data stored in the shared database does not count against the storage quota of the current user’s iCloud account.

However that is unclear as to who pays for content stored in the shared database. So who pays for content stored in the shared database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost will fall on the developer, as stated here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1640408-sharedclouddatabase

> Data in the shared database counts toward your app’s iCloud storage
> quota.

Answer (score 1):

A shared database is actually just a shared view into someone’s private database, so the cost would fall on the private database owner.